# Scraping information from a flash object on a website using python or any other method

Tags: python, flash, web-scraping

I was just wondering if it is possible to scrape information form this website that contained in a flash file.(http://www.tomtom.com/lib/doc/licensing/coverage/)

I am trying to get the all the text from the different components of this website.

Can anyone suggest a good starting point in python or any simpler method.

Comment: I know it has been a very long time , can you please tell me if you were able to scrape the flash site, I am struggling with something similar.

Comment: check cheerio and puppeter

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following blog post answers your question well. The author had the same need, to scrape Flash content using Python. And the same problem came up. He realized that he just needed to instantiate a browser (even just an in-memory one that did not even display to the screen) and then scrape its output. I think this could be a successful approach for what you need, and he makes it easy to understand.

http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/

Comment: Is the link dead, I tried opening it but was not able to open at all

Comment: This is the redirection of archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20151011001233/https://tudorbarbu.ninja/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/

Comment: check cheerio and puppeter

Comment: What do you mean by 'Cheerio and Puppeter'?